# UISearchController: dim overlay covers searchbar itself

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using `UISearchController` in a project targeting iOS 10+, I can set it as `navigationItem.searchController` for iOS 11, but for iOS 10 I have to manually add the search bar.

On iOS 10 there's an issue that when `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` is set to `true`, there's a dimmed overlay when search bar becomes first responder, however it covers not only the search results area, but also the search bar itself.

On iOS 11 it works perfectly.

Is there anything I have to set / change?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add screenshots of results you are seeing for different OS Versions.

Answer (score 1):

Set `definesPresentationContext` to `true`

e.g.

```
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
```